# Default ExUnit.Case to use `async: true`

Tags: elixir

The docs for [ExUnit.Case](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_unit/ExUnit.Case.html) say that the `:async` option defaults to `false` and "should be enabled only if tests do not change any global state". In a project I'm working on <1% of our test cases change global state, but people often forget to add `async: true` to cases that should be async.

Is there a way for a project to instead default `:async` to `true`?

The best solution I've come up with so far is to create my own case template that passes my own default into `use ExUnit.Case`, but I'd like to avoid that if I can. It seems a little weird, and I feel like then people would just forget to use the custom case template. If there was a way to set it in config I'm not finding in the docs, that's more what I'm looking for, I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As might be seen in the source code, `async` attribute goes [directly from the options only](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.8.1/lib/ex_unit/lib/ex_unit/case.ex#L218).

Maybe the pull request doing somewhat like:

```
- async = !!unquote(opts)[:async]
+ async = Keyword.get(
+   unquote(opts),
+   :async,
+   Application.get_env(:ex_unit, :async_all, false)
+ )
```

Comment: Thanks! I would typically check the source code for something like this, but it slipped by mind this time.